# Redis is working although it's returning false on zadd command

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm testing zadd command in redis with nodejs and I wrote the code below:

```
const redis = require("redis");
const { promisifyAll } = require("bluebird");

promisifyAll(redis);

class Cache {
  client: any;

  constructor() {
    this.client = redis.createClient({
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      no_ready_check: true,
      password: "password",
    });
  }

  async zadd() {
    let result = this.client.zadd([
      `person`,
      0,
      `${JSON.stringify({
        id: "aklas-djsadfdf3-034ukf",
        name: "Tiago Ribeiro",
        age: 42,
      })}`,
      0,
      `${JSON.stringify({
        id: "akljsdf-034ukf",
        name: "Cleber Machado",
        age: 29,
      })}`,
    ]);

    console.log(result);

    return result;
      }
}
```

When I call the function zadd(), it returns false. But if I check in redis-cli and do the command `zrange person 0 -1`, it gives the expected output:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zrange person 0 -1
1) "{\"id\":\"aklas-djsadfdf3-034ukf\",\"name\":\"Tiago Ribeiro\",\"age\":42}"
2) "{\"id\":\"akljsdf-034ukf\",\"name\":\"Cleber Machado\",\"age\":29}"
```

Why is the function returning false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the function client.zadd to client.zaddAsync and now it worked as expected

```
 async zadd() {
let result = await this.client.zaddAsync([
  `person`,
  0,
  `${JSON.stringify({
    id: "aklas-djsadfdf3-034ukf",
    name: "Tiago Ribeiro",
    age: 42,
  })}`,
  0,
  `${JSON.stringify({
    id: "akljsdf-034ukf",
    name: "Cleber Machado",
    age: 29,
  })}`,
]);
```